# Canvas - lines drawn but not showing up in google inspect element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to using canvas and am having a weird issue. My canvas lines are successfully being drawn using:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

where canvas is the id of a canvas. I then draw using the methods:

```
    context.strokeStyle = "red";  
    context.beingPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
```

with lineTo being called in a loop updating its position. I use these methods in a function and can draw multiple lines. The issue is (is it an issue?) when I use google's inspect elements I can't find these lines under the canvas that was created. I am used to seeing a path element of some sort.

I can see the script that created these lines, however.

EDIT: just checked another website using canvas and this seems to be normal behavior. Would like confirmation though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It's normal behaviour.
In 2012 the chrome have some experimental plugin with help inspect canvas. But I not sure if it still avaiable (I found information here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/)

Comment: Thanks, its seems weird to a first time canvas user. Glad its not a problem.

Comment: Upvote. Just highlighting that anything drawn onto a canvas element is not "remembered" and becomes un-referenced pixels.